# PDO Two Table Joining

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First table:

[image: 1st Table]

Second table:

[image: 2nd Table]

In the first Table, there will be multiple `given_to` with same `taskid`, and specific to that `taskid` i have set `task` in 2nd table.

Is it possible to obtain the task of a same `taskid` from multiple users to be printed in a table? If so How can we achieve it? 
If possible, I also want to print the columns `given_to` of the task seperated by space.
Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure I understood correctly what you want as a result, but as far as I get it you can achieve this with the correct SQL query, using a simple left join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.taskid = table2.id
```

You might want to replace the `SELECT * FROM ...`  part with the specific fields you are interested in.

For more information about joins (that is: merging results/columns from several tables into one query result) take a look at the [MySQL reference manual on JOIN syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).